# Makefile command to uninstall external kernel modules

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My Makefile for a simple external linux kernel module contains the following lines, the target "`modules_install`" is added to the command to install the module:

```
install: all
    make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=foodir -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
```

What would be the proper command to **uninstall** the module?
Is there an opposite to "`modules_install`"?

Comment: 1) Apparently not about the C language. 2) How about `rm`ing the module?

Comment: @Olaf it might leave the orphaned modules: consider modA <- libmodB + libmodC, if you remove modA, and libmodB + libmodC had been used solely by modA you will get orphaned modules.